# List only users that have changed a certain value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c1503f75621302dd7804614b36ddc24)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    order_number VARCHAR(255),
    customer_number VARCHAR(255),
    customer_score VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(order_date, order_number, customer_number, customer_score)
VALUES 
('2020-04-10', 'Order_01', 'user_01', '1'),
('2020-04-15', 'Order_02', 'user_01', '2'),
('2020-05-18', 'Order_03', 'user_01', '2'),
('2020-05-22', 'Order_04', 'user_02', '1'),
('2020-06-18', 'Order_05', 'user_03', '3'),
('2020-06-26', 'Order_06', 'user_03', '2'),
('2020-07-28', 'Order_07', 'user_04', '2'),
('2020-08-03', 'Order_08', 'user_05', '1'),
('2020-09-10', 'Order_09', 'user_05', '1'),
('2020-09-15', 'Order_10', 'user_05', '1'),
('2020-10-23', 'Order_11', 'user_06', '4');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    order_date  |   order_number  |  customer_number |   customer_score  |
    ------------|-----------------|------------------|-------------------|---------
    2020-04-10  |     Order_01    |     user_01      |        1          |
    2020-04-15  |     Order_02    |     user_01      |        2          |
    2020-05-18  |     Order_03    |     user_01      |        2          |
   -------------|-----------------|------------------|-------------------|---------
    2020-06-18  |     Order_05    |     user_03      |        3          |
    2020-06-26  |     Order_06    |     user_03      |        2          |
```

---

I want to extract all customers and their orders in case the `customer_score` has changed. 
However, I have no clue how I can check in the query if the the `customer_score` has changed between the orders. 
Do you have any idea?

```
SELECT
s.order_date AS order_date,
s.order_number AS order_number,
s.customer_number AS customer_number,
s.customer_score AS customer_score
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `EXISTS` query can be used to check if a different score exists for a customer:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sales AS s1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sales AS s2
    WHERE s2.customer_number = s1.customer_number -- same customer
    AND s2.order_number <> s1.order_number        -- different order
    AND s2.customer_score <> s1.customer_score    -- different score
)
```

Alternately use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find such customers, then find related records:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE customer_number IN (
    SELECT customer_number
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY customer_number
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customer_score) > 1
)
```